# How to compute HDR probability level for Highest density regions estimates

Tags: r, probability, density-function

In the `R` package `hdrcde` by Rob Hyndman for Computation of highest density regions in one and two dimensions, the hdrbw function Estimates the optimal bandwidth for 1-dimensional highest density regions.

In the given example, HDRlevelVal variable is a probability 0

HDRlevel : HDR-level as defined in Hyndman (1996). Setting ‘HDRlevel’ equal to p (0

I have not found the referenced article.

Can anybody give me some information about that article and function.

Is there in `R`, packages that implements this function?

```
HDRlevelVal <- 0.55
x <- faithful$eruptions
hHDR <- hdrbw(x,HDRlevelVal)
HDRhat <- hdr.den(x,prob=100*(1-HDRlevelVal),h=hHDR)
Rhat <- hdr.den(x,prob=100*(1-HDRlevelVal),h=hHDR)
```

Answer (score 3):

The references are given in the help file:

> Hyndman, R.J. (1996). Computing and graphing highest density regions.
>   The American Statistician, 50, 120-126.
>
> Samworth, R.J. and Wand, M.P. (2010). Asymptotics and optimal
>   bandwidth selection for highest density region estimation. The Annals
>   of Statistics, 38, 1767-1792.

I don't know what you mean by asking what packages implement the function. You already know about the `hdrcde` package which implements it in the `hdrbw()` function.

Comment: Thank you Rob. HDRlevelVal, Can you please explain this sentence? : Setting ‘HDRlevel’ equal to p (0<p<1)
corresponds to a probability of 1-p of inclusion in the highest density region. Thank you. Ernest

Comment: So, I understand that HDRlevelVal is a probability value? Ernest

Comment: In fact, I wanted to know how to find the HDRlevelVal value. Is there a function in the package which do the job, or is there any package which have a function which do the job. Thank you.

Comment: You choose whatever you want. If you want a 95% HDR, than set it to 0.95.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob. That's the information I needed. I thought this value was the result of some formula. Is there a way to fine tune this value based on the time series statistics features?